# 7zip - How to overwrite a existing file?

Tags: windows, compression, 7-zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I overwrite an existing file in 7zip?](https://superuser.com/questions/538389/how-can-i-overwrite-an-existing-file-in-7zip)

I'm trying this:

```
7za.exe a "C:\Disc.7z" "C:\test" -v20000000b -m0=BCJ -bd
```

But if I already have created the file "C:\Disc.7z" then 7zip don't compress nothing and sends me this output:

```
System error:
File already exist.
```

I've tryed with the switch "-y", but 7zip is not doing any question...

So... Can't overwrite the file?

> UPDATE

I've tried the switch "-aoa" but does nothing too...

http://docs.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/overwrite.htm

> UPDATE 2

I need a solution using the parameters of 7 zip, not deleting the files first.