# How can I overwrite an existing file in 7zip?

Tags: windows, compression, 7-zip

I'm trying this:

```
7za.exe a "C:\Disc.7z" "C:\test" -v20000000b -m0=BCJ -bd
```

But if I already have created the file `C:\Disc.7z` then 7zip doesn't compress anything and sends me this output:

```
System error:
File already exist.
```

I've tried with the switch `-y`, but 7zip does not do anything...

How can I overwrite the file?

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried the switch `-aoa` but it does not work either...

Comment: Try to do it from an elevated (Run as administrator) cmd

Comment: @Ofiris, that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is it acceptable for 7-Zip to update the existing archives rather than overwriting them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `-v` to create a multi-volume archive. People have been requesting the author for the last 5 years to allow the program to modify multi-volume archives, but he has [no plans](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/1b2e567a) to implement the feature any time soon. (It's open source, wish some enterprising programmer would do it already!)

Answer (score 6):

Try using `7za.exe u` instead of `7za.exe a`. The first one is specifically used to update an archive that already exists.

Comment: thankyou for comment, i've tried but the result is the same: "file already exist"

Comment: 7-Zip normally updates archives if they already exist. The reason it doesn't work in this case is the `-v` switch is being used.

Comment: @Sam that's what I remembered too, but then I thought that maybe using a specific update option could help

Comment: @sam, I've tryed it before post with the -volume switch and without it (and without any other switch), the result is the same (tested with 7zip 7.20 and 7.22 beta), sorry for my english.

Comment: @ElektroHacker, that's interesting. When I test it, if I remove the `-v` switch, everything works correctly; 7-Zip creates the archive if it doesn't exist, and it updates it if it already exists. Don't worry about your English; it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way to have this functionality with command line switches. Overwriting is supported only during archive extraction.

Answer (score 2):

### Work-Around

To work around this problem, you could delete the archive files if they exist before you create them again. Here's one way to do this:

`CMD /C FOR %i IN (C:\Disc.7z.???) DO DEL %i && 7za.exe a "C:\Disc.7z" "C:\test" -v20000000b -m0=BCJ -bd`

### Explanation

- The `CMD /C` ensures that the `7za` command is only executed once rather than for each file.
- The `FOR` iterates through each destination archive file and deletes it. Note that the expression only covers volumes with three-digit suffixes. If you expect more (which I'm not sure is possible), you could replace the `???` with `*`.
- The `&&` runs the second command after the first (if the first is successful).

Comment: Thanks, I know by deleting first the files is a solution... but I'm searching for a solution using the parameters of 7zip.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in 7-Zip, so I suspect that a work-around is your only option outside of changing the source or waiting for a bug fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that this problem doesn't occur for me if I remove the `-v` switch. It appears that 7-Zip doesn't support updating archive volumes.